# How do I trigger an email on customer registration in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

This is my first Magento project.  I've learned how to modify templates & layouts but the last thing I need to do is trigger an email to send to the store owner whenever a new customer registers.

Customers can't see prices or order without registering so I should be able to hook into customer_register_success.  They wouldn't be able to create an account during checkout.

Do I need to create a whole module just for this?  I'm trying to figure out what file I need to write the code on, and where it lives in the Magento filesystem.

Would it go in a helper?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply write observer class to trigger it.. check below link to get an idea about it

http://www.magentothemess.com/archives/1092